# double click on transparent NSWindow title does not maximize the window

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

On High Sierra 10.13, I have a subclass of NSWindowController that configures its window like this:

- Has title bar
- Transparent title bar
- Full size content view
- Has shadow
- Not textured
- Can close, minimize, resize
- Is movable by window background

The problem is that the window can't zoom or minimize when the user double clicks on the title bar.

With the regular title bar, double click works as usual.

I see that many applications with similar NSWindow configuration support the double click (for example Safari).

What am I missing?

Comment: I am seeing the same in Mojave.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @prabhu no, I am sorry. I wrote some code to detect the double click and zoom the window, but then I did not use it, because I changed the window style to a non-transparent title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSWindow` and use the `contentLayoutRect` property to compute the titleBar rectangle. Then trigger a zoom if the double-click is inside that rectangle.

Here is the code in Swift 5:

```
import Cocoa

class MyWindow: NSWindow {

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if event.clickCount >= 2 && isPointInTitleBar(point: event.locationInWindow) { // double-click in title bar
            self.performZoom(nil)
        }
        super.mouseUp(with: event)
    }

    fileprivate func isPointInTitleBar(point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        if let windowFrame = self.contentView?.frame {
            let titleBarRect = NSRect(x: self.contentLayoutRect.origin.x, y: self.contentLayoutRect.origin.y+self.contentLayoutRect.height, width: self.contentLayoutRect.width, height: windowFrame.height-self.contentLayoutRect.height)
            return titleBarRect.contains(point)
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

and for completeness, here is the documentation for `contentLayoutRect`:

> Typically, the area represented by this property is the same as the frame of the contentView. However, for windows with NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask set, there needs to be a way to determine the portion that is not under the toolbar. The contentLayoutRect property contains the portion of the layout that is not obscured under the toolbar. This property is KVO compliant.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this snippet!