# NSWindow with full size content view double click action

Tags: swift, cocoa, xib, nswindow

I've created a new project with an empty `NSWindow` (zero code - simply configured it in .xib) and have set it to show the title bar but hide the title text, along with a transparent title bar & full size content view.

This works - I can drag the transparent title area at the top to drag the window around. However the standard double-click action no longer works.

I've set system preferences to minimize the window on a double click. It does nothing. I could potentially add a fake `NSView` where the transparent title bar is and handle a `mouseUp`, but there seems to be no way to determine if the user has selected "Zoom" or "Minimize".

How do I solve this? The solution [presented in the question seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150960/double-click-on-transparent-nswindow-title-does-not-maximize-the-window), however as I mentioned, I need it to minimize instead of zoom (rather - I want it to perform the default double-click action).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way is to read it off of an undocumented user default:

```swift
if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleActionOnDoubleClick") == "Minimize" { 
  window?.performMiniaturize(nil)
}
else {
  window?.performZoom(nil)
}
```